# Use csv file in junit5

Tags: junit5

Please tell me is there a way to run any test in csv file instead of having to test all cases.

For example i have csv file as follows:

```
{"1,student_1","2,student_2","3,student_3"}
```

I just want to run the test "2,student_2"

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5#5-csv-files

Comment: I mean just want to run 1 test and not skip the subject line